# Need to sort by Expression in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an expression that is returing the exact data I need, however
Access won't allow me to sort by it...which renders the data almost useless.

Expression in Query Designer:

```
DelDays: Workdays(Format([Shipment Date]+1,'0000-00-00'),Format([POD Delivery Date],'0000-00-00'))
```

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT RTGFDXGround.[Invoice Number], RTGFDXGround.[Express or Ground Tracking ID], RTGFDXGround.[Service Type], RTGFDXGround.[Shipment Date], RTGFDXGround.[POD Delivery Date], RTGFDXGround.[Net Charge Amount], RTGFDXGround.[Zone Code], Workdays(Format([Shipment Date]+1,'0000-00-00'),Format([POD Delivery Date],'0000-00-00')) AS DelDays, Mid([Recipient Zip Code],1,5) AS ToZip, RTGFDXGround.[Shipper Zip Code]
FROM RTGFDXGround
WHERE (((RTGFDXGround.[Invoice Number])="6788") AND ((RTGFDXGround.[Ground Tracking ID Prefix])<>"715"))
ORDER BY RTGFDXGround.[Zone Code] DESC , Mid([Recipient Zip Code],1,5) DESC;
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this to sort by 'DelDays' DESC?
I'd prefer to have the logic work in Queries without the need to use a Report.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1):

With SQL you can just put stuff in a sub-query and use the results.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT RTGFDXGround.[Invoice Number], RTGFDXGround.[Express or Ground Tracking ID], RTGFDXGround.[Service Type], RTGFDXGround.[Shipment Date], RTGFDXGround.[POD Delivery Date], RTGFDXGround.[Net Charge Amount], RTGFDXGround.[Zone Code], Workdays(Format([Shipment Date]+1,'0000-00-00'),Format([POD Delivery Date],'0000-00-00')) AS DelDays, Mid([Recipient Zip Code],1,5) AS ToZip, RTGFDXGround.[Shipper Zip Code]
  FROM RTGFDXGround
  WHERE (((RTGFDXGround.[Invoice Number])="6788") AND ((RTGFDXGround.[Ground Tracking ID Prefix])<>"715"))
)
ORDER BY DelDays DESC
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error - that's good, but the query is not returning any results - not good. Maybe something simple?

Comment: well that is the query not the order by... must be in your where statement -- which I have no understanding of.

Comment: ..my fault, I abbreviate the Invoice Number..I am getting the same error which is 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression'. That's the same error I've been getting.

Comment: Remove the quotes around 715 it I'd a number

Comment: ok what are the types of `RTGFDXGround.[Invoice Number]` and `RTGFDXGround.[Ground Tracking ID Prefix]`?  If they are strings then you need to enclose them in quotes.  If they are numbers remove the quotes.  The error you are getting is from the where statement.

Comment: They are strings. I'll try to come up with a different way to get the results I need.

Comment: @Derek is it the double quotes.  Try with single quotes for string constants in sql

Comment: @Derek - "criteria expression" means the `WHERE` clause.  See what happens when you take out the where -- do you get an error then.  If not you know the problem is in the `WHERE` add in one expression, does that work?  add in the other expression, does that work?  Should get to the bottom of the issue quickly if you systematically take out elements to find out where the problem is.